# What's wrong with this perfect number code?

Tags: java, perfect-numbers

I wrote a perfect number program, but when I run it, it outputs that every number is perfect. Please help me find my mistake.

This is my server code:

```
public class Perfect
{
   private int number;

    public Perfect()
    {
        number = 0;
    }

    public Perfect(int num)
    {
        number = num;
    }

    public void setPerfect(int num)
    {
        number = num;
    }

    public boolean isPerfect()
    {
        int number = 0;
        int div = 0;
        int num = 1;
        while (num < number)
        {
            if (number % num == 0)
            {
                div += num;
            }
            num++;
        }

        if ( div == number)
            return true;

        else    
            return false;
    }

   public String toString()
    {
        if (isPerfect() == true)
          return number + " is perfect";
        else
          return number + " is not perfect";
    }
}
```

And the output I got was every number I typed in is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

in `isPerfect` you have defined a local variable `number = 0`. This is the value being tested instead of the field `number`. The local variable is hiding the class field.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is here:

```
public boolean isPerfect() {
    int number = 0;
    ...
```

You should probably be using the object's field `number` instead of shadowing it with a new variable initialized to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The line `int number = 0;` inside the `isPerfect` function is the cause of your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
int number = 0;
int num = 1;
while (num < number)
{
...
}
```

which tests for

```
while (1 < 0)
```

So the loop never runs. Next you have

```
int div = 0;
if ( div == number)
```

which tests for

```
if (0 == 0)
    return true;
```

Therefor every number is perfect.